# New to ROS, want to build a robot =)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I kinda want to imitate this robot: htxp://forums.trossenrobotics.com/showthread.php?4654-Maxwell-A-Mobile-Manipulator

But i want my base to be this one: htxp://www.dfrobot.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=37_111&product_id=63#.UMlFRbT3BT5

So i been thinking to add a computer to it.. Will something like this work: htxp://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813121442 (i got ram/HD and will use this PSU: htxp://www.logicsupply.com/products/picopsu_80, i currently have this battery: htxp://www.batterymart.com/p-12v-7ah-sealed-lead-acid-battery.html )

I want to use a xbox kinetic sensor which connects use to that MB. But i need to use a board to control the servos, ill probably use the arbotix board.

Should i worry about getting that MB, or just get a raspberry pi?

sorry links have an x on them, coulnt post full links

edit #1:

Can you recommend a motherboard + CPU that would be good for this type of task? Thanks

I guess i could go with something like this: htxp://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813186211 and i can pick alot of different types of cpus

when i try to post links it says i dont have enough karma to post links.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50327/new-to-ros,-want-to-build-a-robot-=)/) by [SuperMiguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3779/supermiguel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2012-12-12

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2012-12-13**:
Please use formatting for links, code etc. Oh, and I don't know why you replaced http with htxp, because this will annoy both readers and the automatic linker macro.

**Comment by [SuperMiguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3779/supermiguel/) on 2012-12-13**:
because it says i dont have enought karma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think that even that Atom D525 is going to be slightly under powered when it comes to mapping and controlling arm navigation. So the Raspberry Pi is definitely not going to be suitable for the tasks that Maxwell is capable of.

---

Originally posted by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) with karma: 458 on 2012-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) on 2012-12-13**:
Since you are new to ROS, I would recommend first starting with something like Turtlebot. It has a fair amount of documentation and servo arm upgrades. As writing code for a custom base can become quite complex for the beginner.